# Convexity of sum square over square sum

Tags: convex-analysis, mathematical-physics

Suppose we have a function $$ f(x) = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2} ,$$ where $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)  $ is a vector of non-negative real numbers. We want to determine the convexity of this function. Specifically, we want to answer the question:

Is the function $ f(x) $ convex for $ x \geq 0 $?

I would appriciate any help.

Comment: Please include your thoughts/tries.

Comment: You need to try simple examples. Look at the points were $\|x||_1 = 1$ and $x_k >0$ for $n=2$. Check if $f$ restricted to this line segment is convex.